# No ATTRIBUTE named foo:bar.attribute found from a managed package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, developer-console, aura-attribute

I'll try to be brief as I'm sure this is a basic skill issue with an obvious solution that I'm missing:

I have installed a managed package from AppExchange containing an aura component (From here on *foo:bar*) that I'd like to use in one of my flows. In a new component (*component.cmp*), I reference foo:bar & attempt to define the documented attributes via the syntax:

```
<foo:bar aura:id="x" objectName="y" fieldName="z"></foo:bar>
```

When I attempt to save component.cmp, I get the following error:

```
Failed to save component.cmp: No ATTRIBUTE named foo:bar.objectName found: Source
```

If I instead try to set the attributes via my doInit...

```
...
component.find("x").set("v.objectName","y");
component.find("x").set("v.fieldName","z");
...
```

I'm allowed to save my component, but the component ends up not working while debugging. Running a console.log on these attributes both before and after setting them returns undefined.

The Component Reference and Dev Tools show that these attributes exist as named within the package, but Salesforce isn't acknowledging it. According to the component reference, these attributes are listed as public as opposed to global, which I believe may be related to my problem. Another Managed Package I've used with global attributes lets me get and set them as described above without issue.

Does anyone have any idea how one might interface with these attributes? Unfortunately, the Package itself is very poorly documented and provides no insights on its own. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute has to be marked as global in order to communicate with it outside of the managed package.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Strange someone would release a package on the AppExchange with no way to utilize it.